# MP4 Video format buffering in Android?

Tags: android, buffer, android-mediaplayer

I am working in an application where **RECORD VIDEO and PLAY BUFFER VIDEO** are the major functions.

When I record video in **Android**, that is saved on SERVER and on another screen I got a URL on server of VIDEO, that url is used to play in buffer in MEDIA PLAYER.

The problem is, when the videos which are Recorded and uploaded from iPhone version of this app are not playable in Android app. After buffering I got the below error.

```
02-20 14:13:18.729: E/MediaPlayer(19417): error (1, -2147483648)
```

Videos which are created in Android device, uploaded on the same server are easily buffered and playable in Android device.

Below is the URL of the video which is created from my iPhone :

```
 https://s3.amazonaws.com/WeddingApp/Weddingimage/1642_Video.MP4
```

I am using below code :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_view);
        String videoUrl = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("VIDEO_URL");

        initControls();
        playVideo(videoUrl);
    }
    /**
     * initControls
     */
    private void initControls(){
        try{
            volumeSeekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.sbarvolume);
            audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            volumeSeekbar.setMax(audioManager
                    .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
            volumeSeekbar.setProgress(audioManager
                    .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));   


            volumeSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                {
                }
                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                {
                }
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) 
                {
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                            progress, 0);
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    /**
     * playVideo
     * @param videoUrl 
     */
    public void playVideo(String videoUrl){
        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager
                .LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        mc = new MediaController(this);
        videoView.setMediaController(mc);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoUrl));
        mc.show();
        videoView.start();

        videoView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        videoView.setOnClickListener(this);

        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                VideoActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

Please suggest me.

```
02-20 14:12:26.969: E/MediaPlayer(19417): Uri is  https://s3.amazonaws.com/WeddingApp/Weddingimage/1644_Video.MP4
02-20 14:12:26.969: D/MediaPlayer(19417): http youtube = false, scheme = https
02-20 14:12:26.969: D/MediaPlayer(19417): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
02-20 14:12:27.279: D/memalloc(19417): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x53082000 size:2748416 offset:2134016 fd:191
02-20 14:12:27.409: D/memalloc(19417): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x52579000 size:2134016 offset:1519616
02-20 14:12:27.419: D/memalloc(19417): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x51fd1000 size:634880 offset:20480
02-20 14:12:33.919: E/MediaPlayer(19417): error (1, -2147483648)
02-20 14:12:33.939: E/MediaPlayer(19417): Error (1,-2147483648)
02-20 14:12:33.939: D/VideoView(19417): Error: 1,-2147483648
02-20 14:12:34.239: D/memalloc(19417): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52579000 size:1806336 offset:1519616 fd:160
02-20 14:12:35.289: D/memalloc(19417): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x53321000 size:2093056 offset:1806336 fd:197
02-20 14:12:44.309: D/memalloc(19417): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x53321000 size:2093056 offset:1806336
02-20 14:12:44.309: D/memalloc(19417): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x52579000 size:1806336 offset:1519616
02-20 14:12:44.379: D/memalloc(19417): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51fd1000 size:634880 offset:20480 fd:160
02-20 14:12:44.529: D/memalloc(19417): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x53082000 size:2748416 offset:2134016
02-20 14:12:45.529: D/memalloc(19417): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52579000 size:2134016 offset:1519616 fd:164
02-20 14:13:14.709: E/MediaPlayer(19417): Uri is  http://s3.amazonaws.com/WeddingApp/Weddingimage/1644_Video.MP4
02-20 14:13:14.709: D/MediaPlayer(19417): http youtube = false, scheme = http
02-20 14:13:14.709: D/MediaPlayer(19417): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
02-20 14:13:14.839: D/memalloc(19417): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x52579000 size:2134016 offset:1519616
02-20 14:13:14.839: D/memalloc(19417): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x51fd1000 size:634880 offset:20480
02-20 14:13:14.879: D/memalloc(19417): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51fd1000 size:634880 offset:20480 fd:160
02-20 14:13:18.729: E/MediaPlayer(19417): error (1, -2147483648)
02-20 14:13:18.729: E/MediaPlayer(19417): Error (1,-2147483648)
02-20 14:13:18.729: D/VideoView(19417): Error: 1,-2147483648
02-20 14:13:19.019: D/memalloc(19417): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52579000 size:921600 offset:634880 fd:164
02-20 14:13:20.069: D/memalloc(19417): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x53093000 size:1806336 offset:1519616 fd:197
```

Comment: post full stack trace